# How do I create a txt file with its name coming from a user input

Tags: java, file-io

I want to create a txt file and store it in a particular location such as C:\ or C:\Users.  Also I want the name of the file to be entered by the user as an input.  I have tried it with my codes below but it never works.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cITF implements ICommand{

    @Override
    public void Execute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a file name");
        String filename = scan.nextLine();

        try
        {
            File file = new File(cShell.Currentpath, filename);
            file.createNewFile();

            System.out.println("File created");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to create file");
        }
    }

}
```

where `Currentpath` is a member of `cShell` class and is equivalent to C:\ (the directory to save a txt file).  When it runs it outputs "File created" although nothing is created.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class cShell {

    static String Currentpath="C:\\";
    public String Current = Currentpath;

    static HashMap<String, ICommand> myhashData=new HashMap<String, ICommand>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


    myhashData.put("ls", new cLS());
    myhashData.put("gd", new cGD());
    myhashData.put("md", new cMD());
    myhashData.put("rnd", new cRND());
    myhashData.put("del", new cDEL());
    myhashData.put("hd", new cHD());
    myhashData.put("uhd", new cUHD());
    myhashData.put("ltf", new cITF());
    myhashData.put("nbc", new cNBC());
    myhashData.put("gdb", new cGDB());
    myhashData.put("Tedit", new cTedit());




            System.out.print(Currentpath+"> ");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String Input = scan.nextLine();

            if(myhashData.containsKey(Input))
            {
                ICommand myCommand=myhashData.get(Input);
                myCommand.Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Command");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to print the full filename in your sysout and see what happens

Comment: @vishram0709 why? What's wrong with console input?

Comment: @zencv what did you mean by fullname..?? should I remove the path and put only filename..??

Comment: Sorry guys, when I run this it gives me "Failed to create file" instead of "File Created" as I mentioned above...Any idea why the file is not created in the directory cShell.Currentpath..??

Comment: What is the value of cShell.Currentpath? And does this path exist?

Comment: the value of cShell.Currentpath is C:\ and it exist within another class called cShell

Comment: @user3483389, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying first with some catalog where you definitely have access and print the file path. Then you can check if the files are created in general by your code.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a file name");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();
    try
    {
        File file = new File("/tmp", filename);
        System.out.println("path=" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        file.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("File created");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to create file");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it works if I enter C:\ instead of cShell.Currentpath...say if I enter like C:\\sample.txt instead of providing user input, then it the file created successfully...but that is not what I'm after..I want to the user to provide the name of the file..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: answer below does not reflect original question. Please ignore, taken to comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // open filechooser at user's current location (this will be in your
    // eclipse workspace if running from eclipse (/NetBeans)
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    // just for safety; we're saving files anyhow
    jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    jfc.setDialogTitle("Enter file name and select location . .");
    // null should be the name of the parent JFrame
    int returnVal = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String path = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        writeToCustomFile(path);
    }
}

public static void writeToCustomFile(String path) {
    File f = new File(path);
    // redundancy check, feel free to remove
    if(!f.getPath().equals("")) {
        // create parent directories if they don't exist
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File created");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to create file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a bit different case. My program should be working like a command prompt where by the user should enter some command such as lets say "lft sample.txt" , the program should create a file named sample.txt in a directory give in cShell.Currentpath

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I don't know what your cShell class does, nor can I find it on Google. Can you provide a full working example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

You might be using Windows Vista or latest OS running on your machine.
`Windows doesn't allow you to create files in C:\ folder [root]`

`You can keep some other drive [D:\ or E:\ or C:\somefolder] other than System Related folders` and it will work flawlessly. 
That's a OS restriction to avoid malware/security related problems

Comment: @user3483389, It's never possible with Windows 7 and recent versions of Windows. Just tested now. Btw, creating file and folder is different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876743/creating-file-on-windows-7-causes-access-denied-exception

Comment: Reddy, if it were a permissions issue, he'd get `java.io.IOException: Access is denied` / "Failed to create file". He's getting "File created".

Comment: Any simple way to do this..?? I thought the it's very straight forward somehow I haven't solved it...

Comment: @user3483389, did you change the path to any other hard drives partitions if you have or, change it to your user folder (C:\users\your username)